# VBSCRIPT to read text files from a folder then write into another text file in the same location

Tags: vbscript, fso

I have a folder with text files and data in them, so I want to read all the text files in the folder and write their records into another text file in the same location called `outfile`.

From the code I have tried, I'm able to get the records from the text files into the output file (`outfile`) but my `Do While Not` loop won't terminate. When it reaches the last file it loops again and again from the first file.

I also tried `Do While` loop which give me error.

```vb
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Precious\Projects\Sources\VBS\Testing")
Set outfile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Precious\Projects\Sources\VBS\Testing\testout.txt")

for each file in folder.Files
  Set testfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(file.path, ForReading)

  Do While Not testfile.AtEndOfStream
      line = testfile.readline
      outfile.writeline(line)
  Loop 

  testfile.close
next

outfile.close
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/111825/52365

Comment: For one thing, you'll need to avoid trying to read from the file you're in the process of writing. Updating a file in the same folder might be causing re-enueration of the fiiles there. I suggest writing to a file in the temp folder, then moving it into the target folder after you're done.

Comment: As I understand it FSO keeps active track of the files in the  Files collection, i.e. it detects add/delete/modify and updates it. So as long as you keep writing to a file within the collection of Files, the collection never ends and you end up in a loop.

Comment: Thank you, I created a temp folder for writing to and it worked..

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the list of files includes the newly-created output file. If you must put the output file in the same folder, then get the list of files first:

```
Dim source
source = "C:\Precious\Projects\Sources\VBS\Testing"
Set folder = objFSO.GetFolder(source)
Dim listOfFiles
Set listOfFiles = folder.Files
Set outfile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(source & "\testout.txt")
For Each file In listOfFiles
```

The `listOfFiles` will be a snapshot of the folder when `Set`.

**EDIT:** ChatGPT misled me when it said the files collection was static. But you can MAKE it static by storing it in an array, if you still want it to be in the same file location:

```
Dim listOfFiles()
ReDim listOfFiles(0)
For Each file In folder.Files
    listOfFiles(UBound(listOfFiles)) = file.path
    ReDim Preserve listOfFiles(UBound(listOfFiles) + 1)
Next
ReDim Preserve listOfFiles(UBound(listOfFiles) - 1)
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned

Comment: I did NOT post code generated by ChatGPT. I asked of it the question as to whether the Files collection would be updated by further changes to the file system.